# Remote Event Receiver not firing on App List (or any list)

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

I am trying to create a Remote Event Receiver for whenever an item is adding.

I can't debug it as I have read that debugging Remote Event Receivers requires (Amongst other things) SharePoint 2013 installed on the development server (which mine is windows 7 so I can't install SharePoint 2013). Correct?

So until I setup a virtual box with Windows 2008 server I am flying blind with my Remote Event Receiver.

I have added the `AllItemsReceiver`  to my site with the below XML:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
     <Receiver>
       <Name>AddItemsRecieverItemAdding</Name>
       <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
       <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
       <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AddItemsReciever.svc</Url>
     </Receiver>
     <Receiver>
       <Name>AddItemsRecieverItemUpdating</Name>
       <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
       <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
       <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AddItemsReciever.svc</Url>
     </Receiver>
     <Receiver>
       <Name>AddItemsRecieverItemAdded</Name>
       <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
       <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/AddItemsReciever.svc</Url>
       <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
     </Receiver>
   </Receivers>
 </Elements>
```

Then I have added the following method:

```
  public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
            result.ErrorMessage = "You can not add anything";
            return result;
        }
```

I then install the app, but when I go to lists/mylist and click Add item, it adds without issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should configure service bus to debug remote event receivers.
Please read my two full step-by-step articles (with information about service bus configuration) about Remote Event Receivers in SharePoint Online:

1) Creating and Debugging of Remote Event Receivers for SharePoint Online http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2014/12/creating-and-debugging-of-remote-event.html

2) Adding Remote Event Receivers to list on Host web + Debugging http://blog.virtosoftware.com/2015/01/adding-remote-event-receivers-to-list.html

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score -2):

change the app url to the local hosturl where you app is hosted.

Comment: Can you please add more details about how to do what you propose, and what the purpose is? :)